# Search results: URL of BCS search results start with bdc3://

Tags: search, bcs

I am using sharepoint 2010 Business connectivity service. I need to search an item in the database. So I configured search service. I am able to find the search results but when I clicked on the results , the URL starts from bdc3:// instead of going to profile page. The error showed on the page is "web page cannot be displayed". Please guide me to resolve this problem.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured the profile page before crawling?
Please check if you've done right through the manual:
http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/04/15/how-to-create-a-bcs-profile-page-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx
And remeber please you have to recrawl after creating&configuring a profile page!